# Conditional Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a process that is dumping a CSV file into a temp table then I am formatting the data to put into an actual table.

I have run into an issue where sometimes one of the values is coming up in scientific notation and my table is set to `DECIMAL(13,9)`. Essentially what I am wanting to do is update any of the values that are in scientific notation to 0 because they are so low they might as well be 0 in this use case.

There are 9 columns that could potentially have this scientific notation and I know that I could just have 9 update statements that update each column one at a time. I can do this if I have to, just thought someone might have a better idea than that.

So, my question is: is there a way to update all of these 9 columns with one statement?

Here is the dataset:

```
SELECT Value, MyPropOccupancy, CompSetOccupancy, IndexOccupancy,
       MyPropADR, CompSetADR, IndexADR, MyPropRevPar, CompSetRevPar, IndexRevPar
    FROM #fileColumnsChanges
```

[image]

So in this circumstance, I would want to update CompSetOccupancy (Year To Date) and CompSetADR (Running 12 Month) to 0.

Comment: You cannot. You'll want 9 different update statements. The alternative is updating every single row in each of those columns with a CASE statement that looks for the scientific notation and updates with 0 else with the value, and have 9 columns specified in your UPDATE statement, but that seems like a pretty bad trade-off to just avoid doing 9 update statements.

Comment: That was my second thought and I agree the 9 updates would probably be easier. I was pretty sure that this was the case...thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write just one `UPDATE` here with 9 'setters'. If your numeric values in that temp table are based on `(n)varchar` you need to take this into account before resetting the actual value. Below I used `0.0001` as an example threshold:

```
UPDATE
  #fileColumnsChanges
SET
  CompSetOccupancy = IIF(CAST(CompSetOccupancy AS FLOAT) < 0.0001, 0, CompSetOccupancy)
, CompSetADR = IIF(CompSetADR AS FLOAT) < 0.0001, 0, CompSetADR);
```

Otherwise you can just omit the `CAST`:

```
  CompSetOccupancy = IIF(CompSetOccupancy < 0.0001, 0, CompSetOccupancy)
```

Obviously you have to amend the `UPDATE` with the other fields.

PS
It helps answering questions like these if you'd show us what is/was in the actual #table.

Comment: I think that you forget to take an absolute value of the supplied field.

Comment: Obviously, but in this case my code was just meant as an example on how to avoid having to do more than one update.